# django python ajax java script html

Tags: django, ajax

> ```
> Hello every one , my problem is in django and ajax
> ```
>
> i want to use two block one for django and the other for ajax but the ajax code is not reading , why ?
>
> {% extends 'store/main.html' %}
> {% load static %}
> {% block content %}
>
> // code html
>
> {% endblock content_ajax %}`
>
> ## block content_ajax **your text**%}
>
> ```
>        //code ajax
> ```
>
> {% endblock content_ajax %}`
>
> ```
> #
> ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Inside store/main.html

```
{% block content_ajax %}
{% endblock content_ajax %}
```